# How to not print "empty" list in for loop - Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

The following list is a snippit of output of my code, as you can see it prints [] 3 times at the end, I want to figure out, how to get rid of them.

I have tried a combination of "if not [], 0, '', "", element" at the end of the list comprehension, but it doesn't seem to affect.

Code that outputs it:

```
list = [element.lower() for element in newline.split()]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['do', 'ordain', 'and', 'establish', 'this', 'constitution', 'for', 'the', 'united', 'states', 'of']
['america.']
[]
[]
[]
```

Edit:

```
    input_name = "file.txt"
    inputFile = open(input_name,"r")

    for element in input_name:
        #Reads input
        line = inputFile.readline()
        #Removes newline using slice
        newline = line[:-1] 
        #converts 
        list = [element.lower() for element in newline.split() if not '']
        print(list)
```

file.txt:

do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of
America.

File is a paragraph of text

Comment: Please include the actual code that prints that output.

Comment: Can you show us your input?

Comment: Empty lists are falsy: `print(list or '')`

Comment: Are you trying to print line by lines or word by words?

Comment: If you're running this in a REPL, then no. The point of a REPL is to print the value of the expression you entered. If you have other code to print the list, please include that code. In this case, all you need to do is add an `if`: `if lst: print(lst)`. Also: don't name your variable `list`, it shadows the builtin type `list`

Comment: Added ssnippit of the code

Comment: "I want to figure out, how to get rid of them." What should happen instead? Do you understand why it happens? What is your understanding of why it happens? "I have tried a combination of "if not [], 0, '', "", element" at the end of the list comprehension, but it doesn't seem to affect." Well, yes; no matter what you write in the list comprehension, it will still **create a list**. That is its **purpose**. If you want to *do something else*, rather than create a list, when the `newline` is empty, then that logic has to be external to the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurring because you are, for some unknown reason, looping like this:

```
for element in input_name:
    ..
```

As `input_name` is a string, then this is looping over the characters in the string, meaning you attempt to read eight lines (one for **each character** in the string `file.txt`)

The length of `input_name` has nothing to do with the length of the file …